# como hago que el <th class="ampliar" colspan="3">MAS IVA</th>para ocupar dos filas mas?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: guia]

se desea aplicar hasta  donde dice 3,0%

Comment: Prueba con rowspan="3", es decir, `<th class="ampliar" colspan="3" rowspan="3">`

Comment: Mil gracias , funciono

Comment: Me alegro :-)  He puesto una respuesta con algo de explicación, la cual estaria bien que aceptaras para que la comunidad lo sepa y no se crean que sigue pendiente. Para aprender a aceptar respuestas mírate [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) y para más información sobre porque es importante aceptar las respuesta válida mírate este otro [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). De paso haz el [tour] y gánate tu primera medalla! Gracias por colaborar en el buen funcionamiento del sitio!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal como el OP confirma en los comentarios, la solución ha sido aplicar un atributo nuevo a su columna `<th>`.

En este caso, al tratarse de filas, el atributo aplicado ha sido `rowspan`, el cual, segun esta [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Basics#celdas_que_abarcan_varias_filas_y_columnas) permite elegir varias filas en una tabla, al igual que `colspan` permite elegir varias columnas. En esta otra [documentación](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp) se explica más detalladamente (en inglés).

Por lo tanto, para ocupar dos filas más, la solución ha sido:

```html
<th class="ampliar" colspan="3" rowspan="3">MAS IVA</th>
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que, aunque se quería expandir **2** filas, el valor de este atributo ha de ser de **3** porque también se cuenta la fila actual.

Es HTML básico, pero posteo esta respuesta para que no quede pendiente para siempre.